# Insert json to db

Tags: json, postgresql, command-line-interface

I'm trying to insert json data into db. Sample json:

```json
{ 
"events": 
  [{                                                                                                   
     "timestamp": 1298734,                                                                                               
     "message": "START RequestId: bjn937645",                                                    
     "ingestiontime": 123456                                                                       
  }]
}
```

Table:

```sql
Create table events(id, timestamp, message, ingestion_time)
```

I can get the timestamp and message values but ingestion_time comes in as NULL. I'm trying to get the nested values and convert the epoch timestamp to datetime. Thanks

UPDATE: I'm getting all values, but inserting only 1 record. Trying to insert multiple rows/record.

insert into logging.events(timestamp,message,ingestion_time) select a.json#>>'{events,0,timestamp}', a.json#>>'{events,0,message}', to_timestamp(cast(a.json#>>'{events,0,ingestiontime}' AS BIGINT))
from json_populate_recordset(NULL::logging.events,
'[{
"timestamp": 1298734,
"message": "START RequestId: bjn937645",
"ingestiontime": 123456
},
{
"timestamp": 1298734,
"message": "START RequestId: bjn937645",
"ingestiontime": 123456
}]' :: jsonb) AS a

I tried using json_populate_recordset. Error out: function json_populate_recordset(reportinglogging.events, jsonb) does not exist..

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete and exact `insert` statement you are using ([edit] your question, don't add code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Do you want to "Insert json" or do you want to "Insert values retrieved from json" ?

Comment: 123456 /3600 = 34.29. it's more than 24. So  the last column represent value in seconds?

Comment: for injection_time **123456** do you mean:   12:34:56?

Comment: I want to insert values retrieved from json, and yes Mark I mean 12:34:56. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace  function events_insert(p_object jsonb)
returns setof text AS
$body$
    declare
    p_json_value jsonb;
    v_rec record;
    v_timestamp timestamp;
    v_message text;
    v_time time WITHOUT TIME ZONE;
    v_id bigint;
    begin
    if (p_object['events'] ) is null then raise exception 'no working';
    else
        p_json_value := (p_object)['events'];
        raise info 'p_json_value: %', p_json_value::text;
        raise info 'p_json_value type: %', pg_typeof(p_json_value);
        for v_rec in (select  (jsonb_each_text (jsonb_array_elements
                                                    (p_json_value))).* )
        loop
            case
            when v_rec.key = 'timestamp' then v_timestamp := to_timestamp(v_rec.value::bigint);
            when v_rec.key = 'message' then v_message := v_rec.value;
            when v_rec.key = 'ingestiontime'
                then v_time :=  cast(to_char(v_rec.value::int,'FM999:99:99')as time WITHOUT TIME ZONE);
            else null;
            end case;
        end loop;
        insert into events(timestamp,message,ingestion_time)
                values(v_timestamp,v_message,v_time) returning id into v_id;
        return query select row_to_json(e.*)::text from events e where id = v_id;
    end if;
    end
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

call it:

```
select * from events_insert(
'{"events":
      [{"timestamp": 1298734,
      "message": "START RequestId: bjn937645", 
        "ingestiontime": 123456}]}'::jsonb);
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=beb93331d23f227b726b909b614b2695)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mark, will try that function

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into events (timestamp, message, ingestion_time)
select a.json#>>'{events,0,timestamp}', a.json#>>'{events,0,message}', to_timestamp(cast(a.json#>>'{events,0,ingestiontime}' AS integer))
  from (select
'{ 
"events": 
  [{                                                                                                   
     "timestamp": 1298734,                                                                                               
     "message": "START RequestId: bjn937645",                                                    
     "ingestiontime": 123456                                                                       
  }]
}' :: json AS json) AS a
```

see test in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b21d2c6512776c395d4cdfa4ae567720)

Comment: that worked by casting to BIGINT. How can I insert multiple records?

Comment: you can modifiy the `FROM (SELECT ...) AS a` clause like `FROM (VALUES (...), (...), (...), ...) AS a`

Comment: Thanks @Edourd. I tried modifying the  FROM statement and that works. Appreciated!